# How to efficiently update dataframe cells based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset with information about sales transactions and their corresponding time windows. Some sales transactions are flagged as "corrupt" indicating something wrong. I wish to update these wrong cells with average of the last 3 week at the same time of the day.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a dense dataframe with multiple dates and time intervals
dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", end="2023-12-31", freq="D")
date_indices = np.arange(1, len(dates) + 1)
time_intervals = ["Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", "Night", "Online"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_index": np.repeat(date_indices, len(time_intervals)),
        "time_of_day": time_intervals * len(dates),
        "sales_volume": np.random.randint(50, 100, len(dates) * len(time_intervals)),
        "sales_amount": np.random.randint(2000, 5000, len(dates) * len(time_intervals)),
    }
)

df.loc[(df.date_index > 1000) & (df.date_index < 1050), "corrupt"] = 1

df = df.sort_values("date_index", ascending=False)
```

Below is how I am doing, my confusion: I am able to run it on smaller test dataset as below but, this takes huge time on bigdataset of Million rows. Am I doing it correctly? Or can this be done faster? efficiently?

```py
mask = df["corrupt"] == 1

df["sales_volume_7"] = df.groupby("time_of_day")["sales_volume"].shift(-7)
df["sales_volume_14"] = df.groupby("time_of_day")["sales_volume"].shift(-14)
df["sales_volume_21"] = df.groupby("time_of_day")["sales_volume"].shift(-21)

df["sales_amount_7"] = df.groupby("time_of_day")["sales_amount"].shift(-7)
df["sales_amount_14"] = df.groupby("time_of_day")["sales_amount"].shift(-14)
df["sales_amount_21"] = df.groupby("time_of_day")["sales_amount"].shift(-21)

df["sales_volume_avg"] = (
    df["sales_volume_7"] + df["sales_volume_14"] + df["sales_volume_21"]
) / 3
df["sales_amount_avg"] = (
    df["sales_amount_7"] + df["sales_amount_14"] + df["sales_amount_21"]
) / 3

df.loc[mask, ["sales_volume", "sales_amount"]] = df.loc[
    mask, ["sales_volume_avg", "sales_amount_avg"].values
]
```

Comment: The pandas documentation isn't clear about that but if the `shift` method doesn't modify the underlying object, you would need to create `df.groupby('time_of_day')` only once, assign it to a variable and reuse it.

Comment: got it, will do, anything else apart from that?

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code in a more efficient way by calling [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) only once and using Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) instead of multiplying assignments and operations, like this:

```py
mask = df["corrupt"] == 1
sales = df.groupby("time_of_day")

for col in ("sales_volume", "sales_amount"):
    df.loc[mask, col] = (
        pd.concat((sales[col].shift(-i) for i in (7, 14, 21)), axis=1).mean(axis=1)
    ).loc[mask]
```

Then:

```py
print(df.loc[mask, ["sales_volume", "sales_amount"]])
# Output

      sales_volume  sales_amount
5242     66.333333   4103.000000
5241     82.000000   3169.000000
5240     84.000000   3759.666667
5243     66.333333   3794.666667
5244     73.666667   4678.666667
...            ...           ...
5004     67.666667   2692.000000
5003     65.666667   3004.000000
5002     74.333333   3632.666667
5001     79.666667   4239.000000
5000     66.000000   4392.000000
```